# Constantly checking for new data in web service results in java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: android, android-volley, thread-sleep

I am doing long polling in my app, checking for new data every 500ms then update my textview when there is a new change. It's doing fine but after a few minutes, my app just crashes and gives me this error:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.nativeCreate(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1063)
                                                                                 at com.android.volley.RequestQueue.start(RequestQueue.java:142)
                                                                                 at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:66)
                                                                                 at com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley.newRequestQueue(Volley.java:78)
                                                                                 at com.example.rendell.longpolling.MainActivity.sendRequest(MainActivity.java:96)
                                                                                 at com.example.rendell.longpolling.MainActivity$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:59)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5253)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:900)
                                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:695)
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TextView text;
Date noteTS;

public static final String JSON_URL = "http://192.168.0.100/androidphp/data.php";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);

    (new Thread(new Runnable()
    {

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            while (!Thread.interrupted())
                try
                {
                    Thread.sleep(500);
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // start actions in UI thread
                    {

                        @Override
                        public void run()
                        {
                        // this action have to be in UI thread
                            /*noteTS = Calendar.getInstance().getTime();

                            String time = "hh:mm"; // 12:00
                            text.setText(DateFormat.format(time, noteTS));*/
                            sendRequest();
                        }
                    });
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                    // ooops
                }
        }
    })).start(); // the while thread will start in BG thread
}

public void sendRequest(){

    //While the app fetched data we are displaying a progress dialog
    //final ProgressDialog loading = ProgressDialog.show(this,"Fetching Data","Please wait...",false,false);

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(JSON_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {

                    //text.setText(response);

                    //loading.dismiss();
                    try{
                        showJSON(response);
                    }catch(Exception e) {}
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}

private void showJSON(String json){
    ParseJson pj = new ParseJson(json);
    pj.parseJSON();
    text.setText(ParseJson.playing[0]);
    }
}
```

ParseJson.java

```
public class ParseJson {
public static String[] playing;

public static final String JSON_ARRAY = "result";
public static final String RESULT_ID = "playing";

private JSONArray users = null;

private String json;

public ParseJson(String json){
    this.json = json;
}

public void parseJSON(){
    JSONObject jsonObject=null;
    try {
        jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
        users = jsonObject.getJSONArray(JSON_ARRAY);

        playing = new String[users.length()];

        for(int i=0;i<users.length();i++){
            JSONObject jo = users.getJSONObject(i);
            playing[i] = jo.getString(RESULT_ID);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what is wrong with your code but I can give you few tips

first of all, Read the android documentations on how to make a singleton class for volley, you are creating a new RequestQueue every time you send a request, I use one queue for my whole app, maybe in some cases you create more but I can't think of any right now, most probably this is your main problem since the error is happening at newQueue method

you don't have to make the singleton class but at least try to make the queue as instance variable and add to it each time.

second of all there are simpler ways to perform a task every x seconds, I heared (NOT SURE) that using thread.sleep in android is not recommended

here is how I usually perform such tasks:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
    final Handler handler = new Handler(){
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // do something on UI
        }
    };
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask () {
        @Override
        public void run () {
            //send volley request here
        }
    };
    timer.schedule(task, 0, 60000); // 60000 is time in ms
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try in a moment. Anyway, is there another or better way to check for updates in the webservice other than requesting for data every x milisecond?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure what your situation is, usually in these kind of situations we use push notifications, we let the server notify us of any updates not the other way around

Comment: I just want to get an update on changes on my web service and update the textview. I'm still gonna look into push notifications.

Comment: Hi, I'm getting an error on handleMessage, it says that I have to implement 3 methods. After implementing the 3, a nwe error says handleMessage doesn't implement from superclass something..

Comment: what do you mean you have to implement 3 methods?

Comment: Class 'Anonymous class derived from handler' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method 'publish(LogRecord)' in 'Handler'. Then 3 methods close,flush and publish where required to be implemented. Then after implementing them, there is an error lin on handleMessage which says Method does not override method from its superclass.

Comment: can you show me your code? you are doing something wrong, handler doesn't have these functions , only handleMessage is required , make sure you are using the same class, maybe you have handler class in different package

Comment: check your import statement , the handler I'm using is in android.os.Handler

Comment: My bad, I was using a different import. Anyway it seems to be working and the memory is not leaking.

Comment: Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Rxjava with Retrolambda for this

```
Observable.interval(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.io()).map(tick -> sendRequest()).doOnError(err -> //handle error).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe(//handle subscription);
```

Update:

For java7 and 6 use this

```
.map(new Func1<Long, String>() {
                @Override
                public String call(Long tick) {
                    return sendRequest();
                }
            })
```

sendRequest method

```
private String sendRequest(){ URL url;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    JSONArray response = new JSONArray();

    try {
        url = new URL(params[0]);
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        int responseCode = urlConnection.getResponseCode();

        if(responseCode == HttpStatus.SC_OK){
            String responseString = readStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            Log.v("CatalogClient", responseString);
            response = new JSONArray(responseString);
        }else{
            Log.v("CatalogClient", "Response code:"+ responseCode);
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(urlConnection != null)
            urlConnection.disconnect();
    }

    return response;}
```

and read stream method

```
private String readStream(InputStream in) {
      BufferedReader reader = null;
      StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
      try {
        reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
        String line = "";
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
          response.append(line);
        }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
        if (reader != null) {
          try {
            reader.close();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }
      }
      return response.toString();
    }
```

now in .subscribe() override Action1 and read the string response.

Comment: It says lambdas are not supported at this language level? Do you have a lower java version of this?

Comment: Now I'm getting error on return sendRequest(); line...it says incompatible types?

Comment: make the return type to return result of a network call. example new Func1<Long, String>() { @Override public String call(Long tick){ return sendRequest()} } Basically you don't need volley, just make a plain urlconnection call, it is already async as we have Schedulers.io() in interval constructor.

Comment: I'm really confused, I'm not trying to return anything...I just want to execute my void method..